# LoginForm versus LoginOverlay in Vaadin 14

Tags: authentication, widget, vaadin, vaadin-flow

Vaadin 14 offers two implementations of [`AbstractLogin`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.1.3/com/vaadin/flow/component/login/AbstractLogin.html):

- [`LoginForm`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.1.3/com/vaadin/flow/component/login/LoginForm.html)
- [`LoginOverlay`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.1.3/com/vaadin/flow/component/login/LoginOverlay.html)

➥ What is the difference?

➥ Why should I use one rather than the other?

The Javadoc description for each is identical, with no hint of their difference. The component catalog page for [`Login`](https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-login/java-examples) shows examples for both, but no mention of the difference.

I see from the source code for [`AbstractLogin.java`](https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-login-flow/blob/master/vaadin-login-flow/src/main/java/com/vaadin/flow/component/login/AbstractLogin.java), [`LoginForm.java`](https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-login-flow/blob/master/vaadin-login-flow/src/main/java/com/vaadin/flow/component/login/LoginForm.java), and [`LoginOverflay.java`](https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-login-flow/blob/master/vaadin-login-flow/src/main/java/com/vaadin/flow/component/login/LoginOverlay.java) that `LoginForm` is not much more than just `AbstractLogin`. In contrast, `LoginOverlay` adds several more methods. Some are just decoration such as a header. But some are more mysterious, such as `initEnsureDetachListener`, and checking for illegal state with `UI.getCurrent`.

I am quite curious about why `LoginOverlay` needs these additional methods above and beyond what `LoginForm` has. I am curious not only about providing login features in my apps, but also to learn more about making my own composite components using the login widget as an example or model.

Answer (score 2):

Taken from the Github page here: [vaadin-login](https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-login)

> Vaadin Login consists of two components:
>
> `<vaadin-login-overlay>` is a Web Component providing a painless login experience, part of the Vaadin components. **Component shows the `<vaadin-login-form>` inside of an overlay.**
>
> `<vaadin-login-form>` is a Web Component providing a form to require users to log in into an application.
> `<vaadin-login-form></vaadin-login-form>`

So in case you would like a login form to be shown in an overlay, you should go for the `LoginOverlay` component. Personally, I see it as a wrapper on top of `LoginForm`, which you could add as a standalone component.

**Edit**:
Regarding additional methods like `close`, `setOpened`, `setDescription` and `setTitle`, they are added to handle an overlay and additional properties, which are not present in `LoginForm` element [LoginOverlayElement](https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-login/html-api/elements/Vaadin.LoginOverlayElement)

> `<vaadin-login-overlay>` (a web-component for `LoginOverlay`) is a wrapper of the `<vaadin-login-form>` **which opens a login form in an overlay and having an additional brand part for application title and description**.

`LoginOverlay` is a wrapper (you might think about it like a decorator pattern), adding an additional features on top of existing `LoginForm`.

Regarding `initEnsureDetachListener`,  this is a private method which ensures that in case component is closed (detached), it's also removed from the UI. (It's added to it when `setOpened` is called https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-login-flow/blob/master/vaadin-login-flow/src/main/java/com/vaadin/flow/component/login/LoginOverlay.java#L119)
Also,

> Note: Overlay will be attached or detached from the DOM automatically, if it was not added manually. [LoginOverlay.java#L90](https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-login-flow/blob/master/vaadin-login-flow/src/main/java/com/vaadin/flow/component/login/LoginOverlay.java#L90)

Created a Github ticket to elaborate it also in the official documentation : [Lacking use cases for LoginForm and LoginOverlay](https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-login-flow/issues/84)

Comment: So what is an “overlay” in Vaadin? When/why would I want to use an overlay?

Comment: I don't think Vaadin impose any another other meaning that a commonly used one for overlays: position on top of other elements. In this particular case, this definition is the most appropriate: `In websites, an overlay is graphical content box that appears in the middle of a page, obscuring the background content.` 
So you would use it, when you want a loginform (which is the content inside a  login overlay)to be on top of every other page/view/component (like shown in the first example here https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-login/java-examples)

Comment: See edits made today to my Question. I point out a few mysterious differences in the source code between `LoginForm` and `LoginOverflay`.

Comment: `initEnsureDetachListener` is a private method to ensure that an **overlay** is detached from DOM, once element is closed.
All those methods added are to manipulate the overlay itself (like open and close).